# Styling lost on Bootstrap 3 nav li item inside a div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is an excerpt from a normal bootstrap 3 nav item:

```
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
```

I've left out the irrelevant stuff.

Now in my situation I need *one* of the menu items to be inside a div:

```
<li> <div> <a href="#">Action</a> </div> </li>
```

The problem with this is that it renders as just a plain unstyled link in the wrong place in the navbar, not styled or located in any way similar to the regular bootstrap menu items as in the first example.

That's all I need, to just be in a div, nothing more than what you see there.

I know I could probably edit the Bootstrap css and just add a rule that accommodates this but I really want to avoid that if possible.

The reason why I have to do this is to do with Angular.js and a dynamic menu option and the ng-if element but in short is there a relatively simple way to force the link in the div to style the same as the other bootstrap 3 nav items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, if you change the markup then you need to change the styles. Bootstrap uses many child selectors to do it's dirty business, but not many of them are likely to apply to your specific situation. For [example](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/sytoB/), a single level nav might look like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><div><a href="#">Home</a></div></li>
  <li><div><a href="#">Profile</a></div></li>
  <li><div><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

So you'd have 3 styles to override:

```
.nav-tabs>li>div>a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.nav>li>div>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>div>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>div>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>div>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: default;
}
```

However, I would recommend attacking this at the source instead. If you're looking to use Bootstrap components in Angular then I'd try to leverage the [Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about Bootstrap UI, it looks interesting for other reasons but note they do not have a nav element in it.